# python print only showing locally

Tags: python, linux, unix

Alright so I am building a "Secondary Authentication" piece for some servers. Basically you get prompted for a second set of credentials after SSHing in. Here is the problem I am experiencing...

The script displays properly so long as I run it from the machine doesnt matter if I am sshed in and already authenticated as the user or if I am local. But if I add the script to the profile in question and have it launched as the person comes in as said user none of my print commands display to the screen, but the getpass.getpass('password: ') command does display.

So here is whats not showing, also not even though its doesnt display the word "Username" it still accepts the input.

```
USERNAME = raw_input('Username: ')
```

This is what doesn't show.

```
PSWD = getpass.getpass('Password: ')
```

Here is what a login attempt looks like (it was the wrong password which also should have printed a failure message but as you see it didn't)

```
Last login: Thu Jul  2 15:19:06 2015 from x.x.x.x
unicode_start skipped on /dev/pts/2
unicode_start skipped on /dev/pts/2
test_test
Password:
Connection to x.x.x.x closed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed it to print to stderr instead of stdout

sys.stdout = sys.stderr